# How to Load Latitude longitude from plist?

Tags: iphone

i want to add latitude and longitude in plist and want to show the location on map view.
I am unable to load latitude and longitude in plist.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"map" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *anns = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSLog(@"anns=%@",anns);

for(NSMutableDictionary *note in anns) {
    float realLatitude = [[note objectForKey:@"latitude"] floatValue];
    float realLongitude = [[note objectForKey:@"logitude"] floatValue];
    WHLocationAnnotation* myAnnotation = [[WHLocationAnnotation alloc] init];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
    theCoordinate.latitude = realLatitude;
    theCoordinate.longitude = realLongitude;
    NSLog(@"...abc...%f",[[note objectForKey:@"latitude"] floatValue]);
         myAnnotation.title = [note objectForKey:@"Title"];
    myAnnotation.subtitle = [note objectForKey:@"subtitle"];

    [mapViewForAnnotation setDelegate:self];
    [mapViewForAnnotation addAnnotation:myAnnotation];

}
```

}

I have done this in viewdidload. I am getting latitude longitude with nslog but location is not correct on mapview.

Comment: write the code how are you doing this

Comment: post your code ,what you did

Comment: In the plist, is the key really spelled "logitude" ("n" missing) or is it "longitude"?  Also, use double and doubleValue instead of float.